# Each button click require one click more in cancel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. Each time I click in Confirmation 'Cancel', the next time needs one more click to close dialog.

```
$('.boton-estado').unbind().click(function () {
$('#id_estado').val($(this).val());
$("#estados").submit(function (event) {
    if (!confirm("¿Realizar cambio de estado?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
$("#estados").submit();
});
```

Ideas?
Thx

Comment: Could you please include your html code?

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: put submit button handler outside the button handler

```
$(function(){
$('.boton-estado').unbind().click(function () {
$('#id_estado').val($(this).val());
$("#estados").submit();
});

$("#estados").submit(function (event) {
    if (!confirm("¿Realizar cambio de estado?")) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
});
});
```